# you have exceeded your daily request quota for this API in production mode when build the bundle.js using webpack

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have some trouble with google autocomplete when i use my react project. i made a simple autocomplete component for react, using google autocomplete.

## Autocomplete.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

export default class Autocomplete extends Component{

init=()=>{
    const input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', ()=>{
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    });
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.init();
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" />            
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

i use

> webpack

for start and build my react project. in localhost:8080 port the autocomplete work perfectly.but when i build the project using webpack and host the bundle.js in a server, i get the error such as

> You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account:

i read about this and i understand i should enable billing account. and there are some problem with hit rate of google api and it may occur this problem. but i have to ask this. why the localhost works autocomplete perfect and when it hosted using bundle.js will make error as above. please give me a cause to this?

Comment: I believe localhost HTTP referrer is whitelisted by Google and doesn't check the existence of billing account. This way you can develop application without billing, but for production you must enable billing account.

Comment: @xomena so you say when i build a bundle.js, i must enabled the billing account. could you please explain how they identify this project is run on production mode?

Comment: I think they just check HTTP referrer. If referrer is something different from localhost they apply check for billing account.

Comment: oh!hmm, but i run my project on localhost:8080 webpack server and then i run project on localhost:5498 a iis server. in the iis server, i used the bundle.js file.on localhost:8080 it works, but localhost:5498 it doesn't work with that error. so there are defferent ports and same localhost, why is it?